# Removal of core data object does not nullify all of its relations?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, nsmutableset

I have an entity called *Task* which has a to-one relationship with the entities *TaskTemplate* and *Occurrence*. Both of these entities have to-many relationships with *Tasks*. Deletion rules are set to Nullify.

Within an *Occurrence*, I try to remove all *Tasks*. To do that, I use the following code:

```
- (bool)removeAllTasks
{
    NSMutableSet *tasks = [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"tasks"];
    [tasks removeAllObjects];
    return YES;
}
```

This does not work. Here are Task and Occurrence before the attempted removal:

```
Relationship 'tasks' on managed object (0x1006bd1c0) <Occurrence: 0x1006bd1c0> (entity: Occurrence; id: 0x102119510 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/Occurrence/p1> ; data: {
    ... bunch of properties ...
    taskType = "0x10211a020 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/TaskTemplate/p2>";
    tasks =     (
        "0x1021185e0 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/Task/p3>"
    );
}) with objects {(
    <Task: 0x10c31d700> (entity: Task; id: 0x1021185e0 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/Task/p3> ; data: {
    ... some more properties ...
    occurrence = "0x102119510 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/Occurrence/p1>";
    persons = "<relationship fault: 0x10e049e90 'persons'>";
    startDate = "2013-01-28 11:00:00 +0000";
    type = "0x10211a020 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/TaskTemplate/p2>";
})
)}
```

... and this is the result after `-removeAllObjects`:

```
Relationship 'tasks' on managed object (0x1006bd1c0) <Occurrence: 0x1006bd1c0> (entity: Occurrence; id: 0x102119510 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/Occurrence/p1> ; data: {
    ... bunch of properties ...
    taskType = "0x10211a020 <x-coredata://6A0ECEF9-473D-44B2-9E89-AC15179D7761/TaskTemplate/p2>";
    tasks =     (
    );
}) with objects {(
)}
```

Notice that the *tasks* relationship is now empty, as I would expect it to be. But I would also expect *taskType* to be empty. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I changed the code so I can see if the task is marked as deleted. I have now:

```
- (bool)removeAllEvents
{
    NSMutableSet *tasks = [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"tasks"];
    [tasks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Task *task, BOOL *stop)
     {
    if (![task isDeleted])
         [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:task];
         NSLog(@"Deleted %@", [task isDeleted] ? @"Y" : @"N");
     }];
    [self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    return YES;
}
```

It does show 'Y', to indicate that the task is marked for deletion. A fetchRequest shows me that there are no tasks left in the context. But if I try to save, I get an inconsistency message ("tasks is not valid").

Comment: Using something like `[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:aTask];` for every task in the *Occurrence* works, but why doesn't the `-removeAllObjects` method? I'd think it would Just Work (tm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `removeAllTasks` method does not delete any objects. It only removes the relationships from the *Occurrence* object to the *Task* objects, but the tasks continue to exist. The deletion rules are only applied if an object is deleted (using `deleteObject:`).

Comment: I am not yet real comfortable with core data, so please forgive a silly further question: I am using the `deleteObject:` method now, but  printing [anOccurrence tasks] shows a faulted task, instead of nothing. I deleted the task, so why is it not gone? This is even after a `-processPendingChanges`...

Comment: @markjs: `deleteObject:` removes the object from the store, but as long as you have a pointer (a "strong reference") to the object that objects continues to exist in memory. Fetching any attributes of the deleted object will fail, but `isDeleted` will return YES. - I hope that makes sense, it is a bit difficult to explain.

Comment: It does. So to delete the Tasks I should iterate through all relationships that the Occurrence has, and use `deleteObject` on it. When done, I should then be able to safely save the data file, without inconsistencies. Correct?

Comment: Does not work. If I request the Tasks in the context using a fetch request, I get nothing (correctly, I think). But when I print the number of items in the NSMutableSet occurrence.tasks, I get one item (it's a fault). This item messes up the save; I get an inconsistency. It's driving me nuts :(

Comment: @markjs: Perhaps you have set a "Minimum Count" for the tasks relationship?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did. So I removed the minimum count. It still does not solve the problem. I'll keep on digging!

Comment: @markjs Be careful if you have an `ordered to-many` relationship, it is highly bugged... @MartinR I don't agree that you should remove "by hand" the object to delete from all the relationships, or at least, `Core Data` is supposed to do it for you, normally...
I have opened a related question on this matter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158091/deleting-wont-nullify-until-save-is-it-true

Comment: @Colas: I did not say that you *"should remove by hand the object to delete from all the relationships"*. I only said that removing an object from a relationship does not delete the object and therefore the deletion rules are not applied.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but the problem is that `deleteObject` doesnt remove the object from the relationships.